# Why was this (likely correct) Answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation, deleted-answer

Someone posted [Wireless LAN can't connect with network](https://superuser.com/questions/704740/wireless-lan-cant-connect-with-network) because he couldn't get a Windows XP machine onto a WPA2 Wi-Fi network. Someone else Answered, suggesting he install an update from Microsoft that adds WPA2 support to Windows XP. That Answer was deleted by a moderator even though it was likely the correct solution to the OP's problem. Why?

https://superuser.com/a/704762/30792

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was flagged as being not an answer. And since it was only a link accompanied by "Try installing this", I deleted it.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: @Spiff: Thanks for bringing it to our attention ;)